# Spring Boot Gradle Plugin "Blessed" Dependencies in a multi-project environment

Tags: gradle, spring-boot

In a multi-project Gradle environment, I have the usual **buildscript** block in my parent **build.gradle**:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.1.7.RELEASE")
    }
}
```

However, the dependencies which are supposed to be "blessed" (See [54.2 Declaring dependencies without versions](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/1.1.7.RELEASE/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html)) does not seem to be, since Gradle does not search for the correct version (because there is not version at all). I wonder if I am missing some additional configuration or it's just not possible at this moment to have "blessed" dependencies for a multi-project Gradle environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Applying spring-boot plugin to all projects (not just parent project) should help.

Try:

```
allprojects {
  apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
}
```

EDIT: Andy and I posted the answers almost at the same time. But yes, either allprojects or subprojects should work fine, depending whether you parent project needs the plugin, or not.

Answer (score 5):

You need to apply the Spring Boot plugin to every project that you want to use the Boot-provided dependency versions. As it's a multi-project build (and assuming you want to apply the plugin to every subproject), add the following to your `build.gradle`:

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
}
```